# a method call which will close the window in a thread and stop it

Tags: c#, multithreading, window, progress-bar

Hello currently started on threading in my application. I have a progress bar which is created from a thread and displayed in a window. I am having trouble closing this window and I have also tried the Thread.Abort() method. This doesn't work and I have read up that this isn't the safest way to do it. the code for the thread:

```
    Form window = new Form();
    private void customiseForm()
    {
        window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(330, 100);
        //window = Form.CenterToScreen;
        window.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        window.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.Turquoise;
        window.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Turquoise;
        window.MouseDown += window_MouseDown;
        window.MouseMove += window_MouseMove;
        window.MouseUp += window_MouseUp;
        window.HandleCreated += window_HandleCreated;
        window.HandleDestroyed += window_HandleDestroyed;
        window.TopMost = true;
    }
    public void refreshNotification()
    {
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(
        new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                customiseForm();
                UltraActivityIndicator Indicator = customiseActivityIndicator();
                Indicator.MouseHover += Indicator_MouseHover;
                window.Controls.Add(Indicator);
                window.ShowDialog();
            }
   ));
        backgroundThread.Start();
    }
```

Comment: `refreshNotification` is doing completely UI work, so why you are using thread here?

Comment: as i need this to be running while another thread is doing its task. ie opening a large file

Comment: "I am having trouble closing this window", where the code to close that window? Can you show please.